# IOError: [Errno2] No such file or directory: for input files to flask

Tags: python, python-2.7, api, docker, flask

This is a client file with flask framework running inside my docker container
. I would like to upload files from my local folder  `C:/Users/RB287JD/Desktop/upload/file.txt`

Unfortunately the flask application is unable to find it. If I run this,

```
APP_ROOT = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
UPLOAD_FOLD = '/c/Users/RB287JD/Desktop/upload/'
UPLOAD_FOLDER = os.path.join(APP_ROOT, UPLOAD_FOLD)
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER

class mainSessRunning():

    def __init__(self):
        host, port = FLAGS.server.split(':')
        channel = implementations.insecure_channel(host, int(port))
        self.stub = prediction_service_pb2.beta_create_PredictionService_stub(channel)

        self.request = predict_pb2.PredictRequest()
        self.request.model_spec.name = 'modelX'
        self.request.model_spec.signature_name = 'prediction'

    def inference(self, val_x):
        data = val_x
        self.request.inputs['input'].CopyFrom(tf.contrib.util.make_tensor_proto(data))
        result = self.stub.Predict(self.request, 5.0)
        return result

run = mainSessRunning()


# Define a route for the default URL, which loads the form
@app.route('/pred', methods=['POST'])
def pred():
    f = request.files['file']
    f.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], secure_filename(f.filename)))
    result = run.inference(f)
    rs = json_format.MessageToJson(result)
    return jsonify({'result':rs})
```

It throws error,

> > > File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/werkzeug/datastructures.py",
> > >       line 2725, in save 
> > >               dst = open(dst,'wb') IOError: [Errno2] No such file or directory:'/c/Users/RB287JD/Desktop/upload/File.txt'

But this is where (`C:\Users\RB287JD\Desktop\upload\File.txt`) my file exists.

Comment: Have you tried specyifing the UPLOAD_FOLD like so:
`UPLOAD_FOLD = 'C:/Users/RB287JD/Desktop/upload/File.txt'`

Comment: Yeah If i give that, it says  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/werkzeug/datastructures.py", line 2725, in save dst = open(dst,'wb') IOError: [Errno2] No such file or directory:`'/serving/C:/Users/RB287JD/Desktop/upload/File.txt'` . /serving is a folder inside my docker container.   Its searching inside my docker container . It is unable to access my local folder.

Comment: Try working with absolute path UPLOAD_FOLD = 'C:/Users/RB287JD/Desktop/upload/File.txt'
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = UPLOAD_FOLD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume your Python program does not see your host machine local directory from the container.

You did not provide your dockerfile or docker command you used for running the container. You need to declare a volume in your dockerfile and bind a local directory from your computer to the container volume.

You can find more information about declaring a volume and mounting it here:

- https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/
- https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/

Hope this helps.

Br,

Veikko